# How to programmatically dock a ToolWindow in a Visual Studio AddIn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, docking

I'm developing a Visual Studio AddIn that shows a ToolWindow similar to the usual Toolbox. Now I would like to have it docked just like the normal Toolbox when I open it. This is the code used to open it (`_applicationObject` and `_addInInstance` are the DTE2 and AddIn obtained from the OnConnection arguments):

```
Windows2 wins2obj = (Windows2)_applicationObject.Windows;
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string an = asm.Location;
string className = "MyAddIn.MyToolboxCtl";
object programmableObject = null;
Window windowToolWindow = wins2obj.CreateToolWindow2(_addInInstance, an,
     className, "A caption", aGuid,
    ref programmableObject);
```

I was able to dock this window setting its IsFloating property to false before making it visible:

```
windowToolWindow.IsFloating = false;
windowToolWindow.Visible = true;
```

This is almost OK, but the windows is docked in the lower part of the main window, where you usually find the Output, Watch, Call Stack, and that kind of windows. Is there a way to force it to open on the left, where you usually see the Toolbox?

EDIT:

I tried to dock my window and the toolbox window together creating a LinkedWindowFrame:

```
Window2 w1 = (Window2)wins2obj.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindToolbox);
Window2 frame = (Window2)wins2obj.CreateLinkedWindowFrame(w1, windowToolWindow,
                        vsLinkedWindowType.vsLinkedWindowTypeTabbed);
```

The result is someway similar to what I'm trying to achieve, i.e. the Toolbox and my window are docked together, but the resulting window is floating and not docked to the left side of the main window.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link will be useful for you: [How to: Change Window Characteristics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h41w1yxb.aspx)
Basically you will need to create / retrieve the approprirate WindowFrame and put your window in it.
Hope this helps.